# using a component class with react router v4 throws error

Tags: react-router

i am a react newbie, and every routing example i have found routes to components defined as **const**, but when using a component class with react router v4 the following error is thrown:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
>       at new About (wuwemek.js:34:70)
>    ..."

[jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/wuwemek/edit?js,console,output)

in the following example, routing to {Home} works fine, but routing to {About} throws the above error. relevant code below - please let me know if you need to see more:

```
var { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } = ReactRouterDOM;

const Home = () => <p>home</p>

class About extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<div>about</div>)
  }
}

<Link to="/">home</Link>
<Link to="/about">about</Link>

<Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
<Route path="/about" component={About}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your code.
Your jsbin's setting is incorrect. You should set it as `JSX (React)`, not `ES6/ Babel`.

Comment: holy moly you are right - what a knucklehead i am! thank you so much for pointing this out, and in a kindly manner.   : )